# My else statement on my comboBox state changed event is running while conditions are not met...Java

Tags: java, if-statement

need some help here with my code.
I have a combobox which in the initialization stage, its selectedIndex is set to -1 (empty).

In my state changed listener for the combo box i have the code i will paste below.

What its supposed to do is check if the selected index of the combobox is -1 then do nothing in my if statement, but if the index is not -1 it will print a row on my jTable with some information on it (this is my else statement) based on the selected index and then set the index back to -1 to deselect any items on my comboBox.

It prints the information on m jTable just fine, but the problem is my else statement seems to run even when the selected index for my combobox is -1.

This problem happens the first time i run the program. there is no other code which prints information on my jTable besides this code. please help

```
private void jComboBoxItemNameItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent evt) {                                                   

    if(evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {

        if(jComboBoxItemName.getSelectedIndex() == -1){
            System.out.println("nothing");
        }

    else {
            try {
                addResultOnTable();
                jComboBoxItemName.setSelectedIndex(-1);
                //displaySearchOnTable();

            } 

            catch (Exception ex) {
                System.out.println("comboBox is empty");
                Logger.getLogger(Inventory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No offense meant but your post and your code are really hard to read, please indent a bit all of this, that'll help you get a answer quicker!

Comment: Did you try debugging your code?

Comment: thanks for the indentation suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to set the selected index of the `JComboBox` to -1 (minus one) is through code and not through a user action. When you set the `JComboBox` index to -1 in the code (as you do in the `jComboBoxItemNameItemStateChanged` method), the `JComboBox` fires an `ItemEvent` but it is **always** a DESELECTED state change and never a SELECTED state change. Hence your inner `if` statement will **never** be true. I am referring to this line of the code in your question:

```java
if(jComboBoxItemName.getSelectedIndex() == -1 && firstRun == true){
```

By the way, since you always set `firstRun` to *true* in method `jComboBoxItemNameItemStateChanged`, the `&& firstRun == true` will always be true. Besides which, people usually just write `firstRun`. Since `firstRun` is a `boolean`, there is no need for the `== true`.

All you need to do (in the `jComboBoxItemNameItemStateChanged` method) is print the value of the state change and the `JComboBox` selected index to verify this.

```
private void jComboBoxItemNameItemStateChanged(ItemEvent evt) {
    String state = switch (evt.getStateChange()) {
        case ItemEvent.DESELECTED -> "De-selected";
        case ItemEvent.SELECTED -> "Selected";
        default -> "Unknown";
    };
    System.out.print("State change: " + state);
    JComboBox<?> combo = (JComboBox<?>) evt.getSource();
    int ndx = combo.getSelectedIndex();
    System.out.println(" , index = " + ndx);
}
```

Note that the `JComboBox` index is always set before the above code is executed. The above code also verifies this. So the following statement, in your question, is not true.

> my else statement seems to run even when the selected index for my combobox is -1

Whenever the following condition (also from your code) is true, the `JComboBox` selected index **cannot** be -1 (minus one).

```java
evt.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED
```

Also note that the above code uses [switch expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/language/switch-expressions.html) which were added since Java 12.

I don't mean to be rude or condescending, but my code, above, is one way to [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
your code. Every programmer needs to learn how to debug their code.

Comment: thanks for the help. Please note index -1 is done through code as i highlighted in the first sentence. By the time this code runs, the index will have already been set to -1. And it is true that my else statement runs straight *if* prints out the word "nothing" as it is supposed to...My bad on the first run boolean, i meant to remove that & i later did but the problem persists. Index prints -1 as is supposed to